# iMovie Clip not rendering

Tags: imovie

I imported some videos from my phone onto my laptop. They are mp4 files and when I play them they play properly. However, when I import them into iMovie they are all really laggy and the video lags behind the audio. I tried to delete them and import them again many times and it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you give it time to make the low-res proxy media? [I assume iMovie does that too, like FCP, to speed up playback whilst editing.]

Comment: Import as what?